# design pattern to map many UI actions to one service action

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a situation where in there is a an external service that has one update operation that updates all information about a particular object for example lets says its a UpdatePerson operation.

I have multiple operation in the UI that lets me add/edit the objects properties in this case the personal details and each of this is optional. Example of details I can update are Email, Name, Address, Bank account details, Insurance etc.

Given the above case what should be the design pattern that I should use to create and update the object that needs by the update operation and also call the update operation.

I was thinking of a builder pattern where in I call

```
builder.Init().SetName(<details>).SetAddress(<details>).SetBankAccountDetails().Execute()
```

Is this the best solution or is there any other pattern that I am missing.

FWIW, currently in this application all these are individual pages but I want to make it robust enough to extend into one page if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this article you can find under **Context of design** the design solutions according to the UI you aim to present. So if you to spend some time [here are patterns](http://www.welie.com/patterns/) in Categories for:

1. Basic interactions (look at · Paging · Pulldown Button · Slideshow)
2. Navigating around (look at · Overlay Menu · Repeated Menu · Retractable Menu · Scrolling Menu)
3. Personalizing (look at · Customizable Window)
4. Giving input (look at · Comment Box · Constraint Input · Form)

You'll have to select the most suitable for your case and/or maybe mix them for:

> have multiple operation in the UI that lets me add/edit the objects properties in this case the personal details and each of this is optional.

A very collection of UI Design Patterns, Libs and Practices [can be found here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/).

**Note** that you must select `User needs` section.

You may find these resources helpful:

- [web-ui-design-patterns](http://uxpin.com/web-design-patterns.html)
- [mobile-ui-design-patterns](http://uxpin.com/mobile-design-patterns.html)
- [User-centered_design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-centered_design)

Hope it helps.

- Cheers

Comment: I wasnt talking about design in terms ox UX it was more of a code design pattern